# Improving Arguelles, a beamer theme, section slides

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, sectioning, themes

I found a very neat `beamer` theme (`Arguelles`, https://github.com/piazzai/arguelles) however there are three things that I believe are troublesome with the theme. I am trying to improve them but I am finding myself short of the required knowledge in the `beamer` class and `LaTeX` in general. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This question is about section slides, i.e. slides that inform the audience of a new section, possibly displaying the other sections in semi-transparent, but which should not be counted in the progress bar as a slide of that section.

The theme does not come with section slides that announce a new section. I know one can write something like below. It works alright, but the main issue is that the slide is counted in the progress bar, whereas it would make more sense not to. How to achieve this? I thought `\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}` would help but it did not.

```
\AtBeginSection[]{
\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}
\begin{frame}[plain,standout]
      \centering\large
      \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsection\par
\end{frame}
}
```